# Transaction fees for Google Play using Stripe Connect as intermediate between users and groceries

Tags: google-play, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I want to allow my users to pay food to my **business users** using Stripe Connect. I never used Stripe, but by reading the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide), this seems feasible and relatively easy to implement.

According to this [Google documentation page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9992660), the purchase or rental of physical goods via a given app is not subject to [their fees](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en).
Does this imply that I will not pay any fee to Google, even if I distribute my app via Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case, you should be able to use Stripe instead of Google Play's billing system and not be subject to Google extra fees. That being said, it would depend on how you implement your app. For example, if you were to sell tokens (that were only available in-app) that could be redeemed for food, that would probably still need to use Google's billing system. You should probably write in to Stripe Support (https://support.stripe.com/contact) to talk through what you want and be completely sure.